# How can a java servlet confirm response was received by client

Tags: java, servlets, tcp

I have a java servlet that handles HTTP GET requests from a client. After processing a request, it sends back HTTP 200 OK and the response includes a few hundred bytes of data.

There is a specific error condition where the client is disconnected from the network at just about the same time that the response is sent. The data is written to the output stream by the servlet, and the output stream is flushed, and the timing is such that at the time when the output stream is flushed, the sever doesn't know that the client is not connected. (The connection was cut off abruptly by a point between client and server, so the client doesn't get a chance to properly close the TCP connection - no TCP RST is seen by the server.)

The question is, is there any way for the servlet to detect this condition? I've already checked two things:

1. I'm not getting any exceptions thrown in the servlet. I was hoping that this condition would result in an IOException but that does not seem to be happening.
2. I call PrintWriter.checkError() on the PrintWriter that is being used to write to the client and it returns false (no error) even when this error condition occurs.

So as far as I can tell there's not a way for the server to know this happens. But it seems to me that it should be possible based on lack of acknowledgement from the client's TCP stack. But perhaps this is not exposed to the servlet.

Not sure whether it matters but I'm using Tomcat 7.0.26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't. The response may be completely buffered by the container, and only written after your Servlet code has exited.

You must not build any reliance on the client receiving the response into your application. This is called idempotence: look it up.

Comment: EJP thanks for the answer. I think I understand the idea of idempotence, however what do you mean by "must not build any reliance" can you elaborate? My understanding is not all HTTP methods need be idempotent e.g. POST.